# Word VSTO swallows exceptions at runtime without debugging?

Tags: ms-word, vsto

Place this code somewhere in a Word document level VSTO solution outside of ThisDocument_Startup (create a ribbon button, with a click event):

```
int zero = 0;
int divideByZero = 10 / zero;
```

Start without debugging (Ctrl + F5), Result: Exception is swallowed, the rest of the code fails silently.

The exception *will* be visible if placed in ThisDocument_Startup, but it appears nowhere else. Microsoft's VSTO forums and the MSDN documentation seem to feel Try...Catch should be used - which is not a big deal for known unknowns. What about the unknown unknowns?

All the common ways of dealing with unhandled exceptions for managed code don't seem to work, presumably because of VSTO using managed code with Office COM Interops:

```
//These don't work
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException ...
System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadException ...
```

I've read posts about troubleshooting VSTO code that always seems to lead to placing Try...Catch around practically everything!

Is there any better way to handle known and unknown (now invisible and silent!) failures?

Comment: be careful, the Word will also try to disable the Add-in that throws exceptions ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually it is quite easy, set the environmental variable VSTO_SUPPRESSDISPLAYALERTS to 0 before running the office application, then Office will display exceptions and not kill your add-in during startup when there are issues.

There is also a useful powershell script which will do this sort of stuff for you and is handy when figuring out when VSTO not working at http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/vstotroubleshooter
Get started by running `vstotroubleshooter.ps1 setdbg` which will setup the VSTO_SUPPRESSDISPLAYALERTS env variable for you

Comment: http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/vstotroubleshooter link does not work. It says "The Archive Gallery has been retired."

Comment: Here's the archived link: https://web.archive.org/web/20120106144456/https://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/vstotroubleshooter

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is isolated only to exceptions around the "add-in user interface" - which happens to be a direct setting found here (Word 2007):

Word Options > Advanced > General > "Show add-in user interface errors"

Comment: Do you know if there is an equivalent option for Word 2003? I'm struggling to get proper exception handling working in an MS Word Application level VSTO add-in. I've added the exception handlers as per your question but they never trigger...

Comment: I don't know of one in 2003. For our VSTO applications in Office 2007, we've had to carefully try...catch around everything with logging and safe tear-down for unknown exceptions.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I notice your question was about doc level add-ins. Have you done any app level add-ins and did you manage to get global error handlers working for VSTO application level add-ins, or did you have to put try/catch around everything for them too?

Comment: Yes, similar unfortunate experience with app-level add-ins. I end up placing try..catch at the lowest level of the call stack (which still ends being everywhere) for dealing with exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with an application-level add-in in Word.

If you are running your add-in by launching it from Visual Studio with F5, then you'll always get "unhandled by user code" in VS (eg 2008 SP1), unless:

- you uncheck the Visual Studio setting "Break when an exception is .. user-unhandled"  for CLR exceptions, or
- you liberally apply the [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()] annotation.

Once you've done one of these, UnhandledException/ThreadException seem to work.