# Crash reporting library for VSTO applications

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

I'm working on a VSTO application, clients had some issues with their plugins like crashes.

As iOS Developer i can use tons of libraries to report all crashes on clients devices, like crashlytics.

Is there any equivalent libs for windows VSTO apps?

Also i can't add `try {}catch (e){report(e);}` on every block code that i write, 
i'm looking for something smarter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even thought I agree with the first part of Eugene's answer, I have correction to the second part. There is specific behavior of vsto-addins. They don't allow to catch all unhandled exceptions in one place (you can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018745/word-vsto-swallows-exceptions-at-runtime-without-debugging) and [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/13b5e823-9a63-42a9-a2ad-fed1e70a6e46/catching-unhandled-exceptions?forum=vsto), for example), so you need to introduce try/catch at least in every entry point of your code, like event handlers. Or maybe some other solution exists which I don't know about. In any case, you cannot use the straightforward approach of using Appdomain.FirstChanceException.

Comment: Exception handling and reporting tools are different things. I don't see anything about handling exceptions in my post.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any .Net libraries. VSTO doesn't require anything specific.

For example, you can send an email with the required techniocal information programmatically.