# Excel Add-in not loaded. A runtime error occurred during the loading of the COM Add-In developed Addin using visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, vsto, excel-addins, google-ads-api

We developed Excel Addin using Visual Studio 2015, C#.
I am using .NET framework version 4.5.2 because of a third party adwords API and supports only .NET framework version 4.5.2.
I created exe file and installed in my system. While creating the exe file, there are no errors. 
After installing the exe file, the Addin is loaded but its showing under "InActive Application Add-Ins" 
Below is the error am getting

> “Load Behavior: Not Loaded. A runtime error occurred during the loading of the COM Add-in”.

I checked LoadBehavior in registry file its 3 only. Even I am getting this error please help me out this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like your startup method throws an exception.

Comment: I am not getting any exception in startup method.

Comment: when I am creating exe in visual studio am getting "WARNING: Two or more objects have the same target location ('[targetdir]\system.runtime.interopservices.dll')"

Comment: General trouble-shooting technique for the problem: Make sure ALL the code is in try...catch blocks. Office can throw messages that only percolate up to the .NET code if try...catch is in-place. You might also want to add some logging so that you can see at what point loading is failing.

Comment: i kept all the code in try catch blocks and maintains log  but i am not getting any exception. please any suggestion to resolve this issue.

Comment: I haven't tried it but should be a step in the right direction - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018745/word-vsto-swallows-exceptions-at-runtime-without-debugging